# Where is the location of homebrew installed youtube-dl configuration? [macOS]

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, config, youtube-dl

I am new to youtube-dl and programming in general so this has been a lot for me to get even this far. So homebrew is installed on my Macbook and homebrew was used to install youtube-dl and ffmpeg. I read somewhere about a configuration file located at  **~/.config/youtube-dl/config** on

> https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options

So on the user directory I opened **.config** (found out it was hidden) and no youtube-dl folder found let alone the config file mentioned in the link.
Why is that?
How do I make a configuration file to use?

Answer (score 0):

Like written on the Guthub page:

> Note that by default configuration file may not exist so you may need to create it yourself.

You can simply create the directory `~/.config/youtube-dl` yourself and then use your favorite text editor, place your options in a new file and save it at `~/.config/youtube-dl/config`